# Inject code in the header of my template

Tags: headers

I'd like to inject the name of the author of a post into the header of the page via the author tag.

something like

```
<head>
    <title>FAQs</title>
    <meta name="author" content="My name">
</head>
```

However, I won't be able to find the author name before entering in the loop? So can I still make this change at that time or is too late?
If so, what's the best way to inject code in the header?

I gave a try with the do_action as explained in this [article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-aquainted-with-wordpress-action-hooks) without success.

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

> However, I won't be able to find the author name before entering in
>   the loop?

This isn't completely correct. The `global` variable `$post` is set by `WP_Query` before the Loop begins and is set to the first post in the Loop. Since the main query runs before the template loads that means that `$post` is also set very early. If you are careful, you can use that variable. It should contain the correct data about the post author on single/singular post pages.

Comment: ok, let's say I want to inject something else? What's the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get your author's name before the loop.

```
if (is_singular()) {
    $author_id = get_queried_object()->post_author;
    $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id );
    }
```

Comment: ok, let's say I want to inject something else? What's the best way?